# Why does my turtle bullet leave 2 lines when it moves?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

The program runs fine until the w key is released. The corresponding function for the w key is shoot_key() which sets the position of the bullet turtle to that of the the user turtle(player1) and also sets the pen up and runs the showturtle() function for the bullet making it visible. It then runs the shoot function which is nested inside the shoot_key() every 50 milliseconds using on_timer thus setting the bullet forward 5 pixels while running the checkbullet() function seperatly as 3 functions with each one having the bullet as one argument and one of the other turtles as the other. When the checkbullet function is ran, if any of the turtles are close enough to collide with the bullet, they disappear. When the bullet and another turtle collides with the wall the bullet_end() function starts which when ran hides the bullet and provides the user the onkey inputs so the user can continue to move the player around the screen even press releasing the w key thus repeating the process and firing the bullet turtle. When I run the shoot function however a line follows the bullet turtle despite me putting the penup and a line also a random line comes from the player turtle as well in a random direction and at random length and I can't seem to find out why

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random
from random import randint

#screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)
screen.bgcolor('green')
screen.tracer(3)
#user
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.penup()
#First enemy
player2 = Turtle()
player2.shape('turtle')
player2.penup()
player2.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player2.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#Second enemy
player3 = Turtle()
player3.shape('square')
player3.penup()
player3.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player3.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
#third enemy
player4 = Turtle()
player4.shape('triangle')
player4.penup()
player4.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
player4.setheading(random.randint(1,360))
###4th enemy  
##player5 = Turtle()
##player5.shape('turtle')
##player5.penup()
##player5.setpos(random.randint(-200,200), random.randint(-200,200))
#bullet
bullet = Turtle()
bullet.shape("turtle")
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup
bullet.setpos(random.randint(-200,200),random.randint(-200,200))
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.penup
px = 0
py = 0

def up():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() + 5

    if py >= 200:
        py -= 15

    player.sety(py)

def down():
    global px
    global py
    py = player.ycor() - 5

    if py < -200:
        py += 15

    player.sety(py)

def left():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() - 5

    if px <= -200:
        px += 15

    player.setx(px)

def right():
    global px
    global py
    px = player.xcor() + 5

    if px >= 200:
        px -= 15 

    player.setx(px)




#distance calculator
def checkcollision(t1, t2):
    while t1.distance(t2) < 10:
        t2.setpos(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100))

# the x and y distance that the player2 turtle moves 
dx = 5
dy = 5

def checkbullet(bullet,turtle):
    while bullet.distance(turtle) < 10:
        turtle.hideturtle()



#1st enemy(switch heading)
head = 0
def enemy1():
    checkcollision(player,player2)
    global head
    player2.fd(5)

    x2, y2 = player2.position()
    head = player2.heading()

    if y2 <= -200 or y2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        player2.setheading((head)* -1)

    if x2 <= -200 or x2 >= 200:
        player2.fd(0)
        player2.backward(7.5)
        if head < 90:
            player2.setheading(0 - ((head) * 2))
        if head>90<179:

            player2.setheading((head)/2)

        if head>179<260:
            player2.setheading((head)/3)


        if head>260<361:
            player2.setheading((head)/2)

    screen.ontimer(enemy1,50)

#Second enemy(dx,dy)
def enemy2():
    checkcollision(player, player3)

    global dx
    global dy
    x3, y3 = player3.position()

    player3.setposition(x3 + dx, y3 + dy)


    if y3 <= -200 or y3 >= 200:
        dy *= -1
        player3.sety(y3 + dy)

    if x3 <= -200 or x3 >= 200:
        dx *= -1
        player3.setx(x3 + dx)


    screen.ontimer(enemy2,50)

def enemy3():
    checkcollision(player,player4)
    player4.fd(5)
    x4, y4 = player4.position()
    head3 = player4.heading()

    if y4 <= -200 or y4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.setheading((head3)* -1)

    if x4 <= -200 or x4 >= 200:
        player4.fd(0)
        player4.backward(7.5)
        player4.fd(0)
        if head3 < 90:
            player4.setheading(0 - ((head3) * 2))
        if head3>90<179:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)

        if head3>179<260:
            player4.setheading((head3)/3)


        if head3>260<361:
            player4.setheading((head3)/2)
    screen.ontimer(enemy3,50)
#When bullet hits wall   
def bullet_end():
    screen.listen()   
    screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
    screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
    screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
    screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
    screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")


def shoot_key():


    bullet.setposition(px,py)
    bullet.showturtle()
    bullet.penup

    def shoot():
        checkbullet(bullet,player2)
        checkbullet(bullet,player3)
        checkbullet(bullet,player4)
        bx = bullet.xcor()
        by = bullet.ycor()
        bullet.fd(5)
        if bx>=200 or bx<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()
        if by>=200 or by<=-200:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.backward(7.5)
            bullet_end()

        screen.ontimer(shoot,50)
    shoot()
screen.listen() 
screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
screen.onkeyrelease(shoot_key,"w")



enemy1()
enemy2()
enemy3()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there! You have three usages of `bullet.penup`, which should be `bullet.penup()`. Only with `()` the function is actually called.